# Selenium Reporting

Tags: selenium-webdriver, reporting, qtp

During my experience in Quality Assurance, especially automation testing, I have experienced two functional test tools(QTP and Selenium). In fact, I have noticed that Selenium have more strong points than QTP or it's much more dedicated for complicated web application. But still have one weak point : "Test Reports". For me, I find a big problem in generating reports related to Selenium Test. Otherwise, I find it very easy using QTP.

My question is, What's the best appropriate method used by Selenium Testers to generate tests reports?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using tetng/junit in your framework along with ant/maven then go with XSLT report. Actually it converts `testng-result.xml` into a html report where you can customize html elements as per your requirement.

I love to generate such kind of pattern in html reports:

[image: XSLT_Report]

To generate above:

1. You need to have an xml report which contains status of all the test cases.If you use testng then it will automatically get generated at the end of execution.
2. An xslt converter file which actually contains core logic of html view. It will fetch the test cases related data from xml report file. [XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 3.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/)
3. You should have a target in `build.xml` ([Write a simple build.xml](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html)) to start the report generation process.